# опечатка на странице пользователя

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

на странице пользователя, вкладка *активность* → *все действия* → *рецензии* в подзаголовке, показывающем общее количество проверок, есть опечатка:

- при нулевом количестве: *0 проверок*
- при ненулевом количестве присутствует опечатка: *1234 провер**о**ки* (цифра — произвольная)

p.s. возможно, там и другие количественные формы используются, и тоже, возможно, содержащие опечатки.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Исправил. Как обычно, новая строка выкатится с обновлением интерфейса.

Comment: закрытым багам не требуется от автора какую-нибудь метку добавлять?

Comment: Там есть тег [tag:status-completed], но он доступен только модераторам.

Comment: @VladD, можете @-упоминать меня в чате, когда чините локализацию, чтобы своевременно появлялся [meta-tag:status-completed].

Comment: @Nofate: Понял, спасибо, так и буду делать.